# Can multiple users use the same software simultaneously via xrdp on linux?

Tags: linux, rdp

Currently I am setting up a Linux HPC Server that shall be accessible via xRDP to multiple users.
But I'm still quite fresh in the Linux game, so here we go: My question is whether those users could use the same software simultaneously or not.

Based on the answer a second question arises: Do I need multiple software-licenses for every user that accesses the server or does one license (usually) work?

Comment: "those users could use the same software simultaneously" I don't see any reason why this would not be possible. A program is just some process running, so, except some specific situation, what makes you think it is not possible?

Comment: If the program has some non-shared resource that can't be used simultaneously - like some hardware or a specific file opened for write, or a single-use license,then there can be a conflict.  Otherwise it should work ok.